# tapestry core datefield component downloading datefield.js from tjq module rather than from t5/core

Tags: tapestry

I'm trying to upgrade an exiting project written with Tapestry 5.3.8 to 5.4.1 and having some issues and one of them right now I'm struggling with is a DateField component used in one of the tml file.

On debugging, I found the request to the .js file is http://serverpath/modules.gz/t5/core/datefield.js and in response it gets the javascript code of & from tjq/datefield.js(tapestry5-jquery-4.1.1.jar) and not from t5\core(tapestry-core-5.4.1.jar) which was intended.

I still have configuration.add(JQuerySymbolConstants.SUPPRESS_PROTOTYPE, "false"); and JAVASCRIPT_INFRASTRUCTURE_PROVIDER did not set to jquery so by default in 5.4.1 it should still be Prototype.

Can some one please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out why its doing it that way The new Tapestry jquery 4.1.1 lib is overriding the tapestry core datefield in JQueryAppModule configuration.add("t5/core/datefield", new JavaScriptModuleConfiguration(datefield));